Directory Review to find files that may have File Length Issues: Get-ChildItem exceeding Path limit 260 characters
I'm trying to build a log with filepaths to items on our server that exceed 255 characters. This script works to log items as high as 351 Characters. (I have no idea how an employee was able to save these files, but there's full on sentences in the file name/directory path).
The script is working, in that I've identified 780 files which exceed the acceptable path length for Microsoft PCs. But at the end of the script I get a bunch of errors suggesting this is NOT a complete list.
# The path to scan and the the lengths for (sub-directories will be scanned as well).
$pathToScan = "\\Server\"          #or "\\Server\Share\" 

# This must be a file in a directory that exists and does not require admin rights to write to.
$outputFilePath = "C:\temp\FilePathLengths.txt" 

$Drive = New-PSDrive "X" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $pathToScan
$DriveLength = $pathToScan.Length

$writeToConsoleAsWell = $false   # Writing to the console will be much slower.
 
# Open a new file stream and write all the paths and their lengths to it.
$outputFileDirectory = Split-Path $outputFilePath -Parent

if (!(Test-Path $outputFileDirectory)) { New-Item $outputFileDirectory -ItemType Directory }
$stream = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($outputFilePath, $false)

# Starting effort before this caused errors, tried alternatives
# Get-ChildItem -Path $pathToScan -Recurse -Force | Select-Object -Property FullName, @{Name="FullNameLength";Expression={($_.FullName.Length)}} | Sort-Object -Property FullNameLength -Descending | ForEach-Object {

Get-ChildItem -Path "X:\" -Recurse -Force | Select-Object -Property FullName, @{Name="FullNameLength";Expression={($_.FullName.Length)}} | Sort-Object -Property FullNameLength -Descending | ForEach-Object {
    If ($_.FullNameLength -gt 255) {
    $filePath = $_.FullName
    $length = $_.FullNameLength
    $string = "$length | $filePath"
     
    # Write to the Console.
    if ($writeToConsoleAsWell) { Write-Host $string }
  
    #Write to the file.
    $stream.WriteLine($string)
    }
}
$stream.Close()
Remove-PSDrive "X"

(I've censored out information by putting replacing text WITH 'ScriptPath&Name' - This is the path to the saved script being run.
'FilePath that isn't descriptive enough to actually identify the file' replaced a specific file it had issue with, but doesnt have enough info to identify.)
Error Received:
Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
At 'ScriptPath&Name'.ps1:17 char:1

Get-ChildItem -Path "X:" -Recurse -Force | Select-Object -Property F ...

  + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: ('FilePath that isn't descriptive enough to actually identify the file' :String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand






My goal is to identify ALL directory items that VEEAM/vmware may not correctly handle or recover when we migrate from Server 2012 to 2022. This way we can address them in bulk or individually. I'm open to ideas, but while I'm familiar with Visual Basic, Powershell is new to me.
Thank you!
I tried to log Get-ChildItems to identify files that may not RESTORE to the directory after we build a new server and recover from backups(Using our backup file to RESTORE to a new server). Files with a path greater than 255 characters or 260, or whatever... They don't recover from backups. My script is able to easily identify files greater than the limit. But it still causes 20 or so file errors saying the file name is too long. Despite ALL the results being file name/paths too long.
I've attempted to enable Long Paths in the registry.
I attempted using a temporary PSDrive to truncate the filepath during discovery.
My concern is that I've been able to log items with this revised code up to 350 characters, but it's still getting errors beyond that of path's too long.
I am hoping to have a clear analysis of files that need renaming, because the filepath is too large.
Thank you!

The only way is to mount a drive letter with the root path so the filenames become shorter.  Or start Get-ChildItem from a subfolder.

I am using a mounted Drive letter in this example. Should I test to a more extreme measure? To be clear though, I'm only saving about 16 characters. But my confusion is why I CAN log items up to 350 characters, but there's some hidden figure beyond that I can't log.

The character length is a windows limitation.  At one time it was approximately 128 characters.

Thanks jdweng! That's good to know. But our users have saved files with upwards of 300 characters now. And I don't believe VEAMM/VMWARE is going to recover them during the upgrade. So trying to per-emptively identify which files these might be so I can handle them accordingly.

The save length and read length limits are the same using the full file name. But you can save and read from a subfolder.  But strange things do happen that I cannot explain.  In some cases the full path is returned instead of just the short path name of a file.  I as trying to get a python script bug fixed and never succeeded because I was getting the full path instead of the short path and exceeding the character length.

I'm struggling to understand. Employees have successfully saved files well over the character limit. I will bring fire and brimstone upon them. But I'm trying to understand why this script will identify files well over 300 characters, but simultaneously give me a path limit error for others. Using a mounted drive doesn't seem to change anything. The file output is still the explicit path. I want the explicit path, but I'm unsure how to move forward to filter or improve this.

Mysterious; perhaps enabling long-path support in the registry doesn't apply to UNC paths; you can try using UNC paths directly and prefixing them with \\?\UNC\<server>\<share>

Have you considered maybe using another CLI tool that may do the job you need without hitting the constraints? For example, there's a popular CLI tool called fd. It's extremely fast and can list all files recursively in a directory. You could swap that into your code and it would work perfectly.

@ChadBaldwin : It is a Windows issue not the tool.

You cannot use the explicit path if the length is too long.  You have to break it into a shorter path.  Under certain conditions the OS will automatically take the short path and make it a long path giving an error.
